# Spring Security Permitting even unauthenticated user? whats wrong with this code?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I doing a simple poc of spring security but am running in to issues.
After extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and implementing own UserDetailsService, spring security is permitting all users even without authentication. Please point the flaw in below code

```
...
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MyWebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService myUserDtlSrv;
            
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(myUserDtlSrv);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance(); 
    } 

    @Override 
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
    }   

}
```

my implementation of UserDetailsService

```
...
@Service
public class MyUserDtlSrv implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return new User("a", "a", Arrays.asList());
    }
}
```

Does not spring security secure every url (resource by default)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify what requests are authorized.  The following fragment
authorizes authenticated (by form login) requests.

```java
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/**")
                .csrf(t -> t.disable())
                .authorizeRequests(t -> t.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, is not by default every URL is secured.

Comment: Perhaps it is the default for requests that match an Ant matcher or request matcher.

Comment: cool, what so ever. Thx for pitching in +1